# css file not loading for a particular route in ejs file

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express, ejs

I have two routes for a webpage. I am loading the same app.css file for both pages. The app.css file is inside /public directory.
[my folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIHDV.png)

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get("/", function(req, res) {

    res.render("home.ejs");
});

app.get("/fall/:thing", function(req, res) {
    var thing = req.params.thing;
    res.render("myThing.ejs", {thingVariable: thing});
});
```

Inside my .ejs file i do something like this to load it.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">

<h1>things ejs file</h1>
```

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">

<h1>Home page</h1>
```

The css file only loads for the first page (`"/"`) and does not load for `"/fall/:thing"`. What am i doing wrong. Btw if i rename the second route as `"/:thing"`, the css loads this time. What is the issue here?

Comment: please try `href="/app.css"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `app.js` is present in current directory then indicate it. Something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./app.css">
```